# Why is ACALL instruction a 2 Byte instruction in 8051 microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, intel

> The target address of the subroutine must be within 2K bytes address
>   because only 11 bits of the 2 bytes are used for the address.

(Source: http://iamtechnical.com/call-instructions-in-8051-microcontroller)

Then, how is the ACALL instruction a 2 Byte instruction? It should be a 3 Byte instruction i.e., 1 Byte for `opcode` + 2 Byte for the target address

Comment: Except that it's 2 bytes for the opcode *and* address.

Comment: @KingDukem, recommend you delete your comment and post it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @KingDuken But, then also the number of bits required to get the target address is 10(because of 2^10 = 1k). And 10 bits are greater than 8 bits(or 1byte), so how is the ACALL instruction a 2Byte instruction? I am confused!

Comment: The first byte contains the opcode and 3 address bits. The second byte contains another 8 address bits. That makes 11 address bits, which can address 2 KB.

Comment: @TonyM There ya go haha :P

Comment: -1 ... it appears to me that you did not do any research .... a simple web search for `8051 instruction set` returns this 
 .... http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_acall.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, how is the ACALL instruction a 2 Byte instruction? It should be a 3 Byte instruction i.e., 1 Byte for opcode + 2 Byte for the target address

The instruction encoding for ACALL is a little complicated. It consists of two bytes in the format:

```
/----- first byte ----\   /---- second byte ----\
A10 A9 A8 1  0  0  0  1   A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0
```

*There is no single one-byte "opcode" which corresponds to ACALL*. There are 8 different leader bytes which can be part of an ACALL encoding (11h, 31h, 51h, 71h, 91h, B1h, D1h, F1h), as the top three bits of the first byte contain the high bits of the address.

Comment: Yep. Specifically, there is a 5-bit opcode for ACALL, it just doesn't occupy all of the first instruction byte.

Answer (score 1):

On the very last paragraph of the link you have provided, it's very specific:

> The only difference is that the target address for LCALL can be anywhere within the 64K byte address space of the 8051. The target address of the ACALL must be within 2K byte range. 8051 marketed by different companies, on-chip ROM is as low as 1K bytes. In this case, the use of ACALL instead of LCALL can save the number of bytes of program ROM space.